# Macro de excel que tiene problema al colocar un valor en una pagina web

Tags: html, excel, vba, macros

Estoy haciendo una macro en excel que toma los valores de una hoja de excel y la escribe en una pagina web, escribe algunos valores en algunos campo, pero en otros no me deja escribilo.
A continuacion voy a colocar el codigo de la macro y el codigo HTML de la pagina en donde no me deja escribir:

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
ie.Navigate "https://thisisapage.com"

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0_ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0__customcontrol1_upLevelDiv").Value = Range("B1").Value
ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0_V1_I1_T5").Value = Range("B2").Value

ie.Visible = True
Set ie = Nothing
```

Este es el campo que no me deja escribir el valor alli

```
ie.Document.getElementById("ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0_ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0__customcontrol1_upLevelDiv").Value= Range("B1").Value
```

Y este es el error que muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Run-time error '438':
Object doesn´t support this property or method**

Este es el codigo HTML del campo en donde no me deja escribir el valor

```
<div tabindex="0" title="People Picker" class="ms-inputuserfield ms-inputBox" id="ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0_ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0__customcontrol1_upLevelDiv" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" style="height: 20px; -ms-overflow-x: hidden; -ms-word-wrap: break-word;" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" aria-multiline="true" onkeydown="return onKeyDownRw('ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0_ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0__customcontrol1', 3, true, event);" onkeyup="return onKeyUpRw('ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0_ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0__customcontrol1');" onclick="onClickRw(true, true,event,'ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0_ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0__customcontrol1');" onchange='CustomControl.OnValueChanged("ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0_ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0__customcontrol1");' ondragstart="canEvt(event);" oncopy="docopy('ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0_ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0__customcontrol1',event);" onpaste="dopaste('ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0_ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0__customcontrol1',event);" onfocusin="StoreOldValue('ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0_ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0__customcontrol1'); saveOldEntities('ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0_ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0__customcontrol1'); Sys.UI.DomElement.addCssClass(this, 'ms-inputBoxActive');" onfocusout="if(typeof(ExternalCustomControlCallback)=='function'){ if(ShouldCallCustomCallBack('ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0_ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0__customcontrol1',event)){if(!ValidatePickerControl('ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0_ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0__customcontrol1')){ShowValidationError();return false;}else {ExternalCustomControlCallback('ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0_ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0__customcontrol1');}}} Sys.UI.DomElement.removeCssClass(this, 'ms-inputBoxActive');" name="upLevelDiv" prefercontenteditablediv="true" autopostback="0" isblankruleset="true" onvaluesetfrompicker='CustomControl.OnValueChanged("ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0_ctl00_ctl33_g_208a2c49_d0a0_4f86_8940_a36b9b4b55bd_FormControl0__customcontrol1");' rows="1"><br></div>
```

Comment: ¿un DIV puede tener un valor? ¿No debería irse a un inputbox u otro tipo de control?

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes que opcion me recomendarias para colocar un valor? por que puedo escribir en el por teclado pero por Macro no

Comment: Sin ver la página no podría decirte, por eso digo que lo más normal es que sea otro tipo de control dentro de ese propio DIV. Vas a tener que investigarlo bien.

Comment: como quieres que te la muestre? quieres todo el codigo o quieres que le haga un print de pantalla en donde no me deja?